# Creating a pdf which included many labels and text view full content of view in pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, pdf-generation

My problem is that I have to create a  pdf of my screen text.My view contains a text view which is scrollable.There are many controls on my view like date label, location label etc.. and text view.I am able to create pdf of my text view fill text but I do not know how to get add the date label, location label and other things with text view in my pdf page also.
My code for pdf creation is :

CGRect savedFrame = txtView.frame;

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(txtView.contentSize);
{
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = txtView.contentOffset;

    txtView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    txtView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, txtJEntry.contentSize.width, txtView.contentSize.height);

    CGRect f = txtView.frame;
    CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newFilePath isDirectory:NO], &f, NULL);

    CGPDFContextBeginPage(ctx, NULL);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -txtView.frame.size.height);
    [txtJEntry.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    CGPDFContextEndPage(ctx);
    CFRelease(ctx);

    txtJEntry.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    txtJEntry.frame = savedFrame;
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

As shown in the image , it is screen shot of my view.I need to add the weather, location stars and date in my pdf and as is it shown in the image means the position of these labels should also be same in the pdf.
I cannot take the screenshot of my entire screen because the text view text is scrollable and had more data .

Please help me in how to show these contents also in my pdf.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to take the entire contents of your UIView and turn it into a PDF. I have a category for `UIView` that renders everything on the view into a PDF file. I am successfully using it in one of my Applications.

```
//UIView+RenderPDF.h
@interface UIView (RenderPDF)
- (void)renderInPDFFile:(NSString*)path;
@end


//UIView+RenderPDF.m
#import "UIView+RenderPDF.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (RenderPDF)

- (void)renderInPDFFile:(NSString*)path {

CGRect mediaBox = self.bounds;
CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO], &mediaBox, NULL);
CGPDFContextBeginPage(ctx, NULL);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -mediaBox.size.height);
[self.layer renderInContext:ctx];
CGPDFContextEndPage(ctx);
CFRelease(ctx);
}
@end
```

---

Now, In order to use it, once you `#import UIView+RenderPDF.h` all you have to do is

```
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"export.pdf"]];

[someView renderInPDFFile:documentDirectoryFilename];
```

Resulting in `export.pdf` being saved to your `Documents` directory. Screenshot of **All** elements on your view into a `PDF` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your quick help.What do you mean by [view renderInPDFFile:documentDirectoryFilename];
[someView renderInPDFFile:documentDirectoryFilename];
lines.view and some view.I added my two sub views but only the last one is getting displayed in the pdf.

Comment: I tried the code, the pdf is only showing the last subview added in the file.[last sub view renderInPDFFile:documentDirectoryFilename];

Comment: You shouldn't be rendering the `sub view`, You should be rendering the parent view of the subviews. i,e: if you're adding your subviews like [self.view addSubview:button];, you should be rendering [self.view renderInPDFFile... ]

Comment: I am adding [button renderInPDFFile... ].Then also it wont work

Comment: @Gypsa As I mentioned numerous times. You **DONT** render the `subviews`. You render the parent `UIVIEW` of the Subviews.